# How to make a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

How can i make a bash script for this?My command is :

```
mysql -h(sample) -u(sample) -p -e "insert into databasename.tablename select count( * )from information_schema.processlist;"
```

Truly yours,

Joey

Comment: So what do you want the script to do?

Comment: The logic is i want to insert the data of this information_schema.processlist to another mysql server

Answer (score 1):

```
-bash-4.2$ cat > my_bash_script << "EOF"
> #!/bin/bash
>
> mysql -h(sample) -u(sample) -p -e "insert into databasename.tablename select count( * )from information_schema.processlist;"
> EOF
-bash-4.2$ chmod 755 my_bash_script
```